# Get user input while listening for connections to server using twisted python

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I am currently trying work on a project using Twisted Python, my problem specifically is my attempt to gain user input whilst also listening for connections using listenTCP(). I looked up the problem originally and found that stdio.StandardIO seems the most efficient way of doing so since I am already using Twisted. I have also seen the code examples found on twisted matrix, [stdin.py](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdin.py) and also [stdiodemo.py](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdiodemo.py) however I am struggling with how to apply to example code to my specific problem given I need to read from the socket and also gather user input while performing tcp tasks.

The project I am working on is much larger however the small example code illustrates what I am trying to do and isolates the problem I am having. Any help in solving my problem is really appreciated.

Server.py

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, stdio
from Tkinter import *
import os, sys

class ServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory
        stdio.StandardIO(self)

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.numConnections += 1
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            print 'receiving data'
            print data
        except Exception, e:
            print e

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.numConnections -= 1
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

class ServerFactory(Factory):
    numConnections = 0
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return ServerProtocol(self)

class StdioCommandLine(basic.LineReceiver):
    from os import linesep as delimiter
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write('>>> ')
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.sendLine('Echo: ' + line)
        self.transport.write('>>> ')

reactor.listenTCP(9001, ServerFactory())
stdio.StandardIO(StdioCommandLine())
reactor.run()
```

Client.py

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import os, time, sys
import argparse

class MessageClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendMessage()

    def sendMessage(self):
        print 'sending message'
        try:
            self.transport.write('hello world')
        except e as Exception:
            print e

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'received: ', data
        self.sendMessage()

class MessageClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MessageClientProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection Failed: ', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection Lost: ', reason.getErrorMessage()

reactor.connectTCP('192.168.1.70', 9001, MessageClientFactory('hello world - client'))
reactor.run()
```

At the moment the above code is returning an Unhanded Error as follows. This demonstrates me using stdin, then it returning the data to stdout and a client the connects causing the error:

> python Server.py
>
> >>> hello
>
> Echo: hello
>
> >>> Unhandled Error Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py",
>   line 84, in callWithContext
>
> return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py",
>   line 118, in callWithContext    return
>   self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py",
>   line 81, in callWithContext
>
> return func(*args,**kw)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py",
>   line 149, in _doReadOrWrite
>
> why = getattr(selectable, method)()
>
> --- exception caught here ---
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py",
>   line 1067, in doRead
>   protocol = s

Comment: The end of your traceback seems to be cut off.

Comment: Sorry `protocol = s` is the last line, however that is the total error that is displayed. Just to add, after the client connects to the server the error above is displayed and then I can continue to provide user input. Any further client connections also give the same error.

Comment: That's strange. Looking at the code in tcp.py, line 1067, the line should be `protocol = self.factory.buildProtocol(self._buildAddr(addr))`.

Comment: Mine is also reading the same i.e: `protocol = self.factory.buildProtocol(self._buildAddr(addr))`. I have double checked the error message and the formatting had got messed up on the last couple of lines prior to that which I have corrected.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem locally and on my machine it shows the full traceback. I'll write an answer including the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback you provided seems to be cut off.  I tried to run the code on my machine and it shows this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1067, in doRead
    protocol = self.factory.buildProtocol(self._buildAddr(addr))
  File "Server.py", line 30, in buildProtocol
    return ServerProtocol(self)
  File "Server.py", line 10, in __init__
    stdio.StandardIO(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_posixstdio.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.protocol.makeConnection(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 490, in makeConnection
    self.connectionMade()
  File "Server.py", line 14, in connectionMade
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
exceptions.AttributeError: ServerFactory instance has no attribute 'clients'
```

As can be easily seen with the full traceback, the factory is missing the `client` attribute.  This can be fixed e.g. by adding this to your `ServerFactory` class:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.clients = []
```

Comment: While the above didn't correct the problem completely it led me to think about the suppressed output. I booted up a VM with Ubuntu on and ran the same code, full error messages were showing up and I have now implemented the above answer and rewritten the code since I now have the full picture. I find it strange that on OSX 'el capitan' 10.11.4 with the latest version of twisted I wasn't getting the same errors however I thank you for helping me reach a conclusion to my issue.